# PHP dropdown list with data from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

i have been try for PHP dropdown list with data from a MySQL database.

I have attached my code below, am not getting the dropdownlist .Can anyone help

```
<?php
$conn   =   mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('qsearch',$conn);
$query = "select Category from information";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
echo '<select id="info" name="info">';
echo '<option value="">-select-</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['Category']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Category'];         ?>     </option>
<?php    
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connection is correctly set up? A blank password is still a password that will be filled in.

Comment: what error are you getting..  execute the query manually in phpmyadmin /console and find the result

Comment: If you are going to use mysqli, why are you using: `mysql_connect('localhost','root','');` and `mysql_select_db('qsearch',$conn);`? You should be using: `mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');` and `mysqli_select_db('qsearch',$conn);`

Answer (score 2):

Because half of your functions are from `mysql` and other from `mysqli`

```
$conn   =   mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('qsearch',$conn);

$query = "select Category from information";

$result = mysqli_query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

You need to closely read the documentation first

http://www.php.net/mysqli & http://www.php.net/mysqli_connect